# Help identifying my great grandfather’s biplane

Tags: aircraft-identification, biplane

I was wondering if anyone could identify the plane my great grandfather (Francis W. Reed) is standing in front of? The picture was probably taken in Indiana.

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us where and when this photo was taken?  Are there other photos of the same airplane?  (Can you also state your grandfather's name and any connection to the airplane - pilot? mechanic? pilot's buddy?)

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a location or date for the photo (most likely Indiana). My great grandfather lived in southeastern Indiana and from what I was told he owned and piloted this airplane. His name was Francis W. Reed. Thanks for you help!

Comment: A timeframe might also be helpful 

Comment: My first thought was a Tiger Moth (OY-DIH, perhaps) but the bracing between the wings doesn't match. Shape of the fin does though. These old biplanes were all extensively modified, so it's always hard to be 100% sure.

Comment: My great grandfather is on the left with the bandana. I believe he is in his 40s and was born in 1901. Thank you all again for the help!

Comment: I am not sure it’s a Tiger Moth. The rear horizontal stabilizer sits below the the fuselage. From all the photos I have seen, the Tiger Moth’s sits flush with the upper ridge of the fuselage.

Comment: @Tman I agree, but my gut feel is still some sort of De Havilland

Comment: The horizontal stabilizer position, as Than mentioned, doesn't seem to match any Moth biplane. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Moth It's getting late here, but I'll do more research tomorrow. (cc: @Jamiec)

Answer (score 12):

This aircraft is an **Alexander Eaglerock A-4** registration [NC701H](http://www.airhistory.org.uk/gy/reg_N86.html) built in 1929 by the [Alexander Aircraft Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Aircraft_Company)

There's not much information about this exact aircraft, but the same type features in a great article about *[The First Black Airmen to Fly Across America](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/air-space-magazine/banning-allen-transcontinental-flt-180967706/)*. It turns out there is at least one A-4 still flying - NC6927 - [**which you can see being flown in a short video**](https://vimeo.com/115680221) about one of those aviators, James Banning.

[image: Alexander Eaglerock]

[image: Eaglerock Advert] [source](https://www.pilotsofamerica.com/community/threads/vintage-airplane-ads-warning-lots-of-large-images.60100/)

[image: EagleRock A-4]

Eaglerock A-4 ([source](https://dmairfield.org/Collections/Cosgrove%20Collection/Airplanes/index.html)) - note the deep sides for the forward cockpit, which you can see in your picture.

[image: Eaglerock A-3]

Eaglerock A-3 ([source](https://live.staticflickr.com/4054/4589592543_121b9a2af4.jpg)) - although a different engine, this angle helps makes sense of the struts in your picture.

Comment: Oh good find!! I think this may well be the one.

Comment: At last! Good job 

Comment: That is a *big* airplane-- the guys in the original photo must have been standing *quite* some ways in front of the fuselage, to make the plane look smaller.  (Wingspan is large, and they appear to be standing near wingtip.)  PS -- second photo above-- looks like a rather *low* seating position-- how the heck could the pilot see *anything* at all during the takeoff run?

Comment: The pilot sat behind. The forward cockpit could seat two passengers side-by-side. You are right about the size, I believe the first picture is a montage, I will replace.

Comment: Yes I realize pilot sat behind, I was looking specifically at the last of your pictures when commenting on visibility--

Comment: Wow, that’s it! Thank you so much everyone for the help! Fascinating history as well.